# Keep ViewControllers in Navigation stack

Tags: ios, ios7, viewcontroller

I'm currently developing an app with an slide out menu. I'm using **SWRevealController** and I'm wondering if there's any one that knows how to keep the ViewControllers in the navigation stack so that they don't have to reload every time you switch?
I know this is possible with **MFSlideMenu** but I don't feel like redoing the whole app.
Thanks

Edit:
Im using webViews in two of my eight **ViewControllers** that are being pushed from an **tableView**. So what i would like to do is for the webView not to reload every time you switch view and the back. That means i don't have keep every single **ViewController** in the stack so it takes up unnecessary memory.

Comment: You can keep them in the stack if they are child view controllers of the parent view controller. This will eat up slightly more memory, but they will be around during the app's whole lifecycle, which is nice for certain scenarios.

Comment: When you push your viewController it will added to the navigationController Stack

Comment: But is the parentViewController the rootViewController or the first ViewController that is shown in the app?